# Get all children from a parent row in the same table

Tags: sql

I have a table in the form

```
ID | title | description | children | parentID
1  | par1  | desc_par1   | 2        | 0
2  | chi1  | desc_chi1   | 0        | 1
3  | chi2  | desc_chi2   | 0        | 1
4  | par2  | desc_par2   | 1        | 0
5  | chi3  | desc_chi3   | 0        | 2
```

I need a query that will return a result in the form

```
parent_title | child_title | child_description
par1         | chi1        | desc_chi1
par1         | chi2        | desc_chi2
```

My initial set up was to grab the parents then loop through each parent to get the children. But given the size of the list this can take very long. So I'm trying to do it in a single query to reduce the amount of time it takes. Any suggestions?

Note: My sql skills are not that great and can only perform basic queries. Any resources to learn more complex queries would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 0):

You want `join`:

```
select tp.title as parent_title, 
       tc.title as child_title,
       tc.description as child_description
from t tp join
     t tc
     on tc.parentID = tp.id
where tp.parentId = 0;
```

Comment: where tp.parentId = ? wouldn't that return just one parent and its children? I need all the parents with their children

Comment: That where parentid=0 makes only parent referred not children as first column

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.title parent_title, t2.title child_title
FROM <table_name> t1
LEFT JOIN <table_name> t2 ON t1.id = t2.parentId
WHERE t1.parentId = 0
```